# EF Core readonly property and parametrised constructor does not work

Tags: entity-framework-core

Model:

```cs
class Model {

  public Guid OwnerIdentityGuid { get; } // read only prop

  private Model(Guid ownerIdentityGuid) // camelCase convention should work
  {
    OwnerIdentityGuid = ownerIdentityGuid;
  }
}
```

Model configuration:

```cs
// ...
modelConfiguration
  .Property(m => m.OwnerIdentityGuid)
  .ValueGeneratedNever(); // should make it work with readonly property
// ...
```

When running `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration` I get following error:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Model'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'ownerIdentityGuid' in 'Model(Guid ownerIdentityGuid)

Adding `private set;` to the property fixes the issue. How I can make it work with readonly property?

Using following versions of EF Core packages:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="EFCore.NamingConventions" Version="5.0.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.5">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.5">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

---- EDIT

This actually works, it was misconfiguration in my "real" code.

Comment: It works for me (no repro). Noticed `EFCore.NamingConventions`  3rd party extension, are you sure you are not messing up something with it?

Comment: I am using `options.UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention()` but it changes only db column names (I commented it out and still receiving same error).

Comment: Ok, found the issue, my EntityTypeConfiguration was extending other EntityTypeConfiguration and calling base() in the wron way. My bad, sorry, and thanks for help.